# Ubuntu asks me for a drive on bootup

Tags: 14.04

Whenever I boot up ubuntu asks me for a specific drive media/nuc/500GB. How can I disable this drive?

Contents of etc/fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

#Entry for /dev/sda2 :
UUID=239eef87-dd6d-4364-99c7-6bb5a07cc755   /   ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1
#Entry for /dev/sda1 :
UUID=5481-19AC  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
#Entry for /dev/sdb1 :
UUID=65E3E80C574F48DA   /media/nuc/500GB    ntfs-3g defaults,nosuid,nodev,locale=de_CH.UTF-8    0   0
#Entry for /dev/sda3 :
UUID=7090edf4-d149-42e9-b92c-4822f2d2130c   none    swap    sw  0   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you had an external drive of some sort attached and somehow told it to be permanently mounted.  You need to find the reference in /etc/fstab and either delete it or, preferably, comment it out.

Post the contents of the file on here if you are unsure...

From the terminal, type the following commands:
`cd /etc`
`sudo cp fstab fstab.150209`
`sudo gedit fstab`

Now, in front of the line which starts `UUID=65E3E80C574F48DA   /media/nuc/500GB ...` type the # character.  It should now look like:

`#UUID=65E3E80C574F48DA   /media/nuc/500GB ...`

Save the file and reboot.  if there are any problems you still have the original fstab in fstab.150209.  Once you are happy that all is well you can use   `sudo gedit /etc/fstab/` and delete the line you have just commented out.  Or, if it feels safer, leave it be...

Comment: Hi. I only have a directory fstab.d, which seems empty.

Comment: can you please open a terminal and type the following command:  ls -l /etc/fs*

Comment: It says `-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  479 Jan 25 19:47 /etc/fstab
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  709 Jan 25 19:46 /etc/fstab-ntfs-config-save

/etc/fstab.d:
insgesamt 0` 
What do I have to do next?

Comment: OK, the first line shows that the fstab file exists.  Next step is to open the file in an editor and take a look.  Initially we don't want to edit the file so please now type the following command:  `gedit /etc/fstab` then copy the contents of the file & post them on here.

Comment: Thank you. I've posted the content in my original post above.

Comment: I've edited my answer with the commands you need... should sort it out!